# Adding multiple dropdown lists into table populated with database values

Tags: php, javascript

I have created dynamic table, which add row at the end after clicking a button. In one column I have `dropdown list` which I want to contain database values.
Here is how I create my table:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createRow() {  
        var row = document.createElement('tr'); // create row node
        var col = document.createElement('td'); // create column node
        var col2 = document.createElement('td'); // create secondcolumn node
        var col3 = document.createElement('td'); // create next  node
        var col4 = document.createElement('td'); // create next column node
        var col5 = document.createElement('td'); // create next column node
        row.appendChild(col); // append first column to row
        row.appendChild(col2); // append second column to row
        row.appendChild(col3); // append next column to row
        row.appendChild(col4); // append next  column to row
        row.appendChild(col5); // append next column to row
        col.innerHTML = '<select name="search-alias-0017" id="hasla" title="Search in">' +
            '<option value="aps" selected="selected">--Wybierz z listy--</option> ' +
            '<option value="stripbooks">opcja</option>' +
            '<option value="popular">Haslo2</option>' +
            '</select>';

        c//rest columns
        var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify"); // find table to append to
        table.appendChild(row); // append row to table
    }
</script>
```

Right now I have `drop down list` with two options. I modified this and loaded some variables from my database, and I want those values to be putted into `<option>` tags. Actually my `JS`looks:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function createRow() {  
<? $q = "select name from vulnerability";
        $result = $db - > query($q) - > fetchall(); ?>
        var options = '';
        options += '<select name="search-alias-0017" id="hasla" title="Search in">';
        for (var i = 0; i < <? echo $result(sizeof($result); ?> ; i++) {
            options += '< option > <? echo $result[i]['name ']; ?> < /option>';
    }
    options+='</select > ';
            var row = document.createElement('tr'); // create row node
            var col = document.createElement('td'); // create column node
            var col2 = document.createElement('td'); // create secondcolumn node
            var col3 = document.createElement('td'); // create next  node
            var col4 = document.createElement('td'); // create next column node
            var col5 = document.createElement('td'); // create next column node
            row.appendChild(col); // append first column to row
            row.appendChild(col2); // append second column to row
            row.appendChild(col3); // append next column to row
            row.appendChild(col4); // append next  column to row
            row.appendChild(col5); // append next column to row
            col.innerHTML = options;

            c//rest columns
            var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify"); // find table to append to
            table.appendChild(row); // append row to table
        }
    </script>
```

But somehow my code doesnt work... can someone give me a hint what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to first execute

```
col.innerHTML = '<select name="search-alias-0017" id="hasla" title="Search in">' +
            '<option value="aps" selected="selected">--Wybierz z listy--</option> ' +
            '<option value="stripbooks">opcja</option>' +
            '<option value="popular">Haslo2</option>' +
            '</select>';
```

and then

```
row.appendChild(col);
```

Making changes to `col`won't make any change if you do it after appending. When you append, `appendChild()` function copies it's input parameter, so after that you don't have access to it the way you tried to do.

Comment: It is not the problem i guess because first script I posted works as It should. Problem Is this part:`options += '< option > <? echo $result[i]['name ']; ?> < /option>';` because `i` variable is not passed correctly. I put there `0` value and then I had whole `dropdown list` populated with the same value

Comment: Ok, I guess I found it:
`<? echo $result(sizeof($result); ?>` - wrong use of brackets.

Comment: still not this. This loop is being count correctly. The line I posted in my previous comment is being the problem.

Comment: Ok, so here it is. I guess you mix things between JS and PHP too much. You can't access `i` JS iterator while iterating in PHP. Better approach would be converting whole PHP array to JS one BEFORE operating on it. This code is full of bugs... Try to write things simplier, don't mix it too much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in appending your rows, so try to redfine table variable:

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
table.appendChild(row);
```